# Convert this connection code from Loom testnet to Goerli Testnet

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, goerli, truffle-hdwallet-provider, convert

This is a utils/common file for connecting to Loom testnet.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const { Client, NonceTxMiddleware, SignedTxMiddleware, LocalAddress, CryptoUtils, LoomProvider } = require('loom-js')

function loadAccount (privateKeyFileName) {
  const extdevChainId = 'extdev-plasma-us1'
  const privateKeyStr = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFileName, 'utf-8')
  const privateKey = CryptoUtils.B64ToUint8Array(privateKeyStr)
  const publicKey = CryptoUtils.publicKeyFromPrivateKey(privateKey)
  const client = new Client(
    extdevChainId,
    'wss://extdev-plasma-us1.dappchains.com/websocket',
    'wss://extdev-plasma-us1.dappchains.com/queryws'
  )
  client.txMiddleware = [
    new NonceTxMiddleware(publicKey, client),
    new SignedTxMiddleware(privateKey)
  ]
  client.on('error', msg => {
    console.error('Connection error', msg)
  })
  return {
    ownerAddress: LocalAddress.fromPublicKey(publicKey).toString(),
    web3js: new Web3(new LoomProvider(client, privateKey)),
    client
  }
}

module.exports = {
  loadAccount,
};
```

I have tried changing stuff in this for ethereum but I haven't been successful completely. Please, can anyone help?

```
const { HDWalletProvider } = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider")
const Web3 = require("web3")
const fs = require('fs')
const { Client } = require('pg')


function loadAccount () {
  const goerliChainId = '5'
  const privateKey = "7661f071e911505b958b37d34AAAAAXXXXXb5d8a14aacc697abdc6f8bec283ec"
  const publicKey = "0x802C196b5XXXXX43040da28DAAAAADAa4Ae6887a"
  const client = new Client(
    goerliChainId,
    'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/zEsvEP-zrKtsYcfLZ2Cr64kuugnfvd6P'
  )
  client.txMiddleware = [
    new NonceTxMiddleware(publicKey, client),
    new SignedTxMiddleware(privateKey)
  ]
  client.on('error', msg => {
    console.error('Connection error', msg)
  })
  return {
    ownerAddress: LocalAddress.fromPublicKey(publicKey).toString(),
    web3js: new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(client, privateKey)),
    client
  }
}

module.exports = {
  loadAccount,
};
```

Target function is,

```
async function init () {

    const { ownerAddress, web3js, client } = common.loadAccount(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME)
    const oracleContract = await getOracleContract(web3js)
    filterEvents(oracleContract, web3js)
    return { oracleContract, ownerAddress, client }

}
```